Make clock update in real time by passing variable from PHP to javascript
I can make a clock appearing with correct time based on $time_zone1. So far so good. The only problem is that the clock does not update every second - or at all. I have struggled with solution where time is created in javascript (instead of using $current_time_formatted), but that did not work as javascript always created clock using my local time instead of the time set in $time_zone1.
Also, I want to be able to change 'America/New_York' to other time zone. So, in PHP, I will fetch a certain time zone, say that now $time_zone='Europe/London'. So, somehow I have to tell javascript to create clock for 'Europe/London', instead of 'America/New_York'.
That is,
$time_zone1 = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone($time_zone))

<?php
// Create a DateTime object for the current time
// 'America/New_York', 'Europe/London', 'Asia/Tokyo'
$time_zone1 = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

// Format the current time
$current_time_formatted = $time_zone1->format('H:i:s');
?>

<!-- Display the clock -->
<div id="clock"><?php echo $current_time_formatted; ?> America/New_York</div>

<!-- JavaScript for updating the clock -->
<script>
function updateTime() {
    // Get the clock element
    var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
    
    // Update the clock display using the PHP variable directly
    clock.innerHTML = '<?php echo $current_time_formatted; ?>' + ' America/New_York';
}

// Update the clock every second
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
</script>


The echo $current_time_formatted is populated when the PHP code runs once on the server, it won't change every time you call updateTime() unless you call the server again. Your JS code runs in the browser, hence it showing the local time rather than the server time.

You can make the time in JavaScript for a specific timezone using Intl.DateTimeFormat
<?php
$time_zone = "America/New_York";
?>

<!-- Display the clock -->
<div id="clock"> <?php echo $time_zone; ?></div>

<!-- JavaScript for updating the clock -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function updateTime() {
            let options = {
                timeZone: "<?php echo $time_zone; ?>",
                timeStyle: 'medium',
            };

            formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options);

            // Get the clock element
            var clock = document.getElementById('clock');

            // Update the clock display using the PHP variable directly
            clock.innerHTML = formatter.format(new Date()) + ' <?php echo $time_zone; ?>';
        }

        // Update the clock every second
        setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    })
</script>


Thanks. I have updated my question. The thing is, I do not want the code to be static just for  timeZone: 'America/New_York'. I want to be able to fetch timezone in PHP and use that for javascript.

Updated the code as per the questions requirement

Thanks a lot!! Is it possible to change   clock.innerHTML = formatter.format(new Date()) + ' America/New_York'; as well?

Check if updated code works... u can update the $time_zone to "Asia/Tokyo" to verify

You could extend the idea of a simple clock using a simple custom-component  so that all the clock functionality is self-contained and easily customisable using PHP to write the necessary timezone to the HTML element.
The custom-component class uses the Intl.DateTimeFormat to render the time in your selected format, again customisable by editing the dataset attributes for the component.


class SimpleClock extends HTMLElement{
    static get observedAttributes(){ 
      return [
        'data-timeZone',
        'data-timeStyle'
      ]
    };

    constructor(){
      const self=super();
      this.shadow=this.attachShadow( { mode:'open' } );
    };

    create(){
      return new Promise( ( resolve, reject )=>{
        let style=document.createElement('style');
            style.textContent=`
            div{
              width: 150px;
              border: 2px solid grey;
              border-radius: 0.5rem;
              padding: 0.5rem;
              margin: 0.5rem 0.25rem;
              
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
              
              color: grey;
              background: whitesmoke;
              box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem silver;
              font-family: monospace;
              font-size: 0.95rem;
            }
            
            div:after{
              content: attr(data-timezone);
              color: black;
              font-size: smaller;
            }
            
            div:before{
              content:attr(data-time)
            }`;
        this.shadow.appendChild( style );
        this.node=this.shadow.appendChild( document.createElement('div') );
        this.node.dataset.timezone=this.dataset.timezone;
        resolve( true )
      });
    };

    render(){
      return new Promise( ( resolve, reject )=>{
        const IntlDateFormatter=function( date, args={} ){
          let options=Object.assign( 
            { timeStyle:'short', timeZone:'Europe/London' }, 
            args 
          );
          return new Intl.DateTimeFormat( [], options ).format( date )
        };
        
        let args={
           timeZone:this.dataset.timezone,
           timeStyle:this.dataset.timestyle
        }
        
        this.node.dataset.time=IntlDateFormatter( new Date(), args );
        resolve( true );
      });
    };

    connectedCallback(){
      this.create()
        .then( bool=>setInterval( this.render.bind( this ), 1000 ) )
        .catch( console.info )
    };
  }
  
  window.customElements.define( 'simple-clock', SimpleClock );
simple-clock{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:1rem 0.5rem;
}
<simple-clock data-timeZone='Europe/London' data-timeStyle='long'></simple-clock>
<simple-clock data-timeZone='Europe/Paris' data-timeStyle='long'></simple-clock>
<simple-clock data-timeZone='Europe/Dublin' data-timeStyle='medium'></simple-clock>
<simple-clock data-timeZone='America/New_York' data-timeStyle='medium'></simple-clock>
<!--

<simple-clock data-timeZone='<?php echo $time_zone1;?>' data-timeStyle='medium'></simple-clock>
-->



